# stopPropagation of any child tags there are inside a parent tag

Tags: jquery

How can I `stopPropagation` of any items there are inside of the div with the class `stopPropagation`?

http://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/xL7s0e9r/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="accordion" id="accordion" >
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" href="#" style="padding: 10px;">
          <div class="btn-group pull-right stopPropagation">
              <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-table"></i></span>
              <a target="_new" href="http://www.google.com">Link 1</a>
              <i href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', '_blank');" class="fa fa-align-left"></i>
          </div>
        Item #1
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class=" collapse in">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" href="#" style="padding: 10px;">
        <div class="pull-right"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
          Item #2
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class=" collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" href="#" style="padding: 10px;">
        <div class="pull-right"><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
          Item #3
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class=" collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not find any div with class stopPropagation. Will you please elaborate more on your exact problem.

Comment: `<div class="btn-group pull-right stopPropagation">`. I have 3 'types' of links inside that div. Only the `a` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.accordion-heading a').click(function(e)
{
  var shouldStop = $(this).closest('div').hasClass('stopPropagation');
  if(shouldStop === true)
  {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

**Updated answer:**

As mentioned in comment below, this is implementation specific and could do with some cleanup if it is being re-used or needs to cater for other scenarios.

```
$('.accordion-heading .stopPropagation').on('click', function(e)
{  
  var elem = $(e.target);
  var modal = elem.is('[data-toggle="modal"]') 
    ? elem 
    : (elem.closest('[data-toggle="modal"]').length === 1)
        ? elem.closest('[data-toggle="modal"]')
        : null;

  if(modal !== null)
  {
    $(modal.attr('data-target')).modal('show');  
  }
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: Well I updated your jsfiddle and it is not propagating the event ... how do you see it not working - perhaps I misunderstood. http://jsfiddle.net/xL7s0e9r/1/

Comment: the collapse shouldn't collapse in or out when click in one of the 3 icons on the right

Comment: the data-target=""  attribute is doing this - can you just remove that if you don't want the toggle behavior?

Comment: I need to collapse it. But If I click in any of the 3 itens on the right, it shouldn't collapse. Only the `a` tag item is working with the original code.

Comment: This works but is implementation specific so it could do with some cleanup - http://jsfiddle.net/xL7s0e9r/3/